# Printing binary string in assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, printing, x86-64

I'm writing a program to print binary string of a hardcoded word. Here is how it looks like currently:

`main.asm`

```
section .text
    global _start
    extern _print_binary_content

_start:
    push word [word_to_print] ; pushing word. Can we push just one byte?
    call _print_binary_content

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

section .data
    word_to_print: dw 0xAB0F
```

`printer.asm`

```
SYS_BRK_NUM equ 0x0C
BITS_IN_WORD equ 0x10
SYS_WRITE_NUM equ 0x01
STD_OUT_FD equ 0x01
FIRST_BIT_BIT_MASK equ 0x01
ASCII_NUMBER_OFFSET equ 0x30

section .text
    global _print_binary_content

_print_binary_content:
    pop rbp

    xor ecx, ecx ;zeroing rcx
    xor ebx, ebx ;zeroing rbx
    pop bx  ;the word to print the binary content of

    ;sys_brk for current location
    mov rax, SYS_BRK_NUM
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
    ;end sys_brk

    mov r12, rax ;save the current brake location

    ;sys_brk for memory allocation 16 bytes
    lea rdi, [rax + BITS_IN_WORD]
    mov rax, SYS_BRK_NUM
    syscall
    ;end sys_brk

    xor ecx, ecx
    mov cl, byte BITS_IN_WORD - 1; used as a counter in the loop below

    loop:
        mov dx, bx
        and dx, FIRST_BIT_BIT_MASK
        add dx, ASCII_NUMBER_OFFSET
        mov [r12 + rcx], dl
        shr bx, 0x01
        dec cl
        cmp cl, 0
        jge loop

    mov rsi, r12
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE_NUM
    mov rdi, STD_OUT_FD
    mov rdx, BITS_IN_WORD
    syscall

    push rbp ; pushing return address back
    ret
```

If I compile link and run this program it works. But the question is about performance and maybe conventions of writing assembly programs. In the file `printer.asm` I cleaned `ecx` twice which looks kind of not optimal. Maybe some registers were used not by their purpose (I used [***intel-manual***](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf)).

Can you please help me to improve this very simple program?

Comment: You could also try the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/184843/printing-binary-string-in-assembly

Comment: Use full registers when possible. Pass arguments in registers, if not, use RSP relative addressing and not push/pops (especially 16-bit versions). You can move a bit off a register into the CF and then ADC to get a 30h or 31h ('0' or '1') into a register. Allocate objects (read: space) on the stack unless you want them to be passed around (remember to free memory, though in this case it doesn't matter).